# $f:\mathbb Z^+\to\mathbb Z^+$ satisfying $f(n+1)\in\{4f(n)-1,f(n)-1\}$, with a unique $n\in\mathbb Z^+$ such that $f(n)=m$ for all $m\in\mathbb Z^+$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, functional-equations

This is functional equation problem from BMO 1999 Q5. The question states:

> Consider all functions $ f $ from the positive integers to the positive integers such that
>
> **(i)** for each positive integer $ m $, there is a unique positive integer $ n $ such that $ f ( n ) = m $ (i.e. the function is *onto*).
>
> **(ii)** for each positive integer $n$, we have $f(n + 1)$ is either:
> $$ 4 f ( n ) - 1$$
> or
> $$ f ( n ) - 1 \text . $$
>
> Find the set of positive integers $ p $ such that $ f ( 1999 ) = p $ for some function $ f $ with properties **(i)** and **(ii)**.

How do I start this question. I can see that $ 4 f ( n ) - 1 $ is always odd. I've also tried plugging in some values after letting $ f ( n + 1 ) = f ( n ) - 1 $ but that hasn't really helped me find an opening.

Solutions focused on how to think through the question will be most appreciated!

Comment: Condition (i) is stronger than *onto*--since the word *unique* is there, the function is also *one-to-one*. In other words, the function is injective and surjective--it is bijective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at this question, the first thing that stands out is that being bijective (as noted in a comment, the condition is much stronger than being onto) is a *very* strong condition — so strong that it's an interesting starting point for exploration.  For instance, there's some unique $m$ with $f(m)=1$. Now, what can this $m$ be? Well, either $1$ was our initial value (i.e. $f(1)=1$) — and I'll come back to that case in a bit — or else we have $f(m-1)=2$. Now, suppose that *this* isn't the initial value of $f()$; then we have to have had $f(m-2)=3$.  But I also know that $f(m+1)$ will be equal to $4f(m)-1=4\cdot1-1=3$, so this is a contradiction; it *must* be the case that either $f(1)=1$ or $f(1)=2, f(2)=1$.

More generally, suppose I take some 'forward step' $f(m+1)=4f(m)-1$ and that I've already accounted for all the values $\leq f(m)$. Then how can I get all the values that are less than $f(m+1)$? They can't be generated 'from below', because I'd have to go back to a value I've already generated (contradicting the conditions of the problem); this means they must be generated 'from above'. But this then locks in a stretch of values of $f()$ — can you see why?  And by iterating this process, the entire question is answered.

Comment: Hi, I haven't had time to digest your whole answer, but one thing stands out to me: "because I'd have to go back to a value I've already generated (contradicting the condition of being onto);" it seems like you think it has to be injective.

Comment: It does have to be injective: "there is a **unique** positive integer $n$ such that..."

Comment: Ohhh alright, that makes more sense; if injectivity would not be required then the answer is just $\mathbb{N}$.